# Java Swing adding Image for Rock Paper Scissors not showing up when I Run it

Tags: java

I've been searching where did I go wrong with the code there's no error or red lines within my codes yet when I run it seems like my Images wont show up can anyone tell me where did I go wrong with this?

```
class btnPlay implements ActionListener{
ImageIcon PaperVec,RockVec,ScissorVec;
    public btnPlay(){
    Play.addActionListener(this);
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    JFrame Play = new JFrame();
    Play.setTitle("ROCK, PAPER, SCISSOR");
    Play.setSize(375,375);
    Play.setVisible(true);
    
    PaperVec = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("PaperVec.png").getImage()
                     .getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        
    RockVec = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("RockVec.png").getImage()
                     .getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                     
    ScissorVec = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("ScissorVec.png").getImage()
                     .getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    
    JLabel PaperLabel = new JLabel();
    PaperLabel.setText("PAPER");
    PaperLabel.setIcon(PaperVec);
    PaperLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    PaperLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    PaperLabel.setBounds(150,300,100,100);
       
    JLabel RockLabel = new JLabel("ROCK");
    RockLabel.setText("ROCK");
    RockLabel.setIcon(RockVec);
    RockLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    RockLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    RockLabel.setBounds(150,300,100,100);

    JLabel ScissorLabel = new JLabel();
    ScissorLabel.setText("SCISSOR");
    ScissorLabel.setIcon(ScissorVec);
    ScissorLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    ScissorLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    ScissorLabel.setBounds(150,300,100,100);
    
    add(PaperLabel);
    add(RockLabel);
    add(ScissorLabel);
    
}
```

Comment: According to the code in your question, Java will search for the three PNG files in the working directory. It appears that the PNG files are **not** in that directory. What is the path to the PNG files - relative to the location of file `btnPlay.class` ? By the way, there are many similar questions already on SO. Enter the following in the search box at the top of this Web page: **[swing] icon resource**

Comment: 1. Don't set bounds manually, use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). 2. It seems that the images are not added to `Play` 3. For more help post [mre].